# Angularjs Select Option set to first item did not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angular and semantic ui. I am trying to make a selection of Y and N through a select option. Basically i just want the first item was selected when the page show up. Tried many ways but i couldn't make it works.

Please take a look at this plunker.

```
angular.module('myapp', [])

.controller('testctrl', function ($scope){
  $scope.add = {};
  $scope.Consigns = [{value: 'N',label: 'N'}, {value: 'Y',label: 'Y'}];
  $scope.add.consign = $scope.Consigns[0].label;
})

.controller('testctrl1', function ($scope){
  $scope.add = {};
  $scope.Consigns1 = [{value: 'N',label: 'N'}, {value: 'Y',label: 'Y'}];
  $scope.add.consign1 = $scope.Consigns1[0].label;
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/cHcLd14xKFxLMS4uy0BM?p=preview

Comment: you should init your add.consign when with the complete object not just the by the label

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: @Erez what you mean by complete object? please see the update plnker

Comment: same as Dev-One answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the model value in default placeholder. Rather than sending the `label` value in `$scope.add.consign` you could send the whole object and print whats required.

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XeuiS7p3K1OOx5nHL9c5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:**

```
 $scope.ListOrder =
        [
            { Name: "price", Id: 1 },
            { Name: "exist", Id: 2 },
            { Name: "Sale", Id: 3 },
            { Name: "New", Id: 4 }
        ];
 $scope.Order = { Name: "exist", Id: 1 };
```

**HTML:**

```
 <select ng-model="Order" ng-options="obj.Name for obj in ListOrder"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 <script>
   $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
</script>
```

and also change select tag to this

```
 <select ng-model="add.consign" class="ui fluid dropdown" ng-options="x.label as x.label for x in Consigns">
          <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: removing the script tag will remove some style of the dropdown which i wish to be kept, although it works in your ways